# Getting 'Bad input data provided to execute_block' when running try-runtime's follow-chain

Tags: try-runtime

When I use the `follow-chain` subcommand I am getting the following error:

```
2023-03-17 16:22:15.698 ERROR main runtime: panicked at 'Bad input data provided to execute_block: Codec error', /Users/bruno/src/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:351:1    
2023-03-17 16:22:15.705 ERROR main try-runtime::cli: failed to execute block 199 due to Input("failed to execute TryRuntime_execute_block: Execution aborted due to trap: unreachable")
```

Steps to reproduce:

Clone repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template
cd substrate-node-template
git checkout polkadot-v0.9.37
```

Run a dev chain locally. This is the chain that I want to "follow":

```
cargo b -r
cp target/release/node-template .
./node-template --dev
```

Compile with try-runtime:

```
cargo b -r --features=try-runtime
cp target/release/node-template node-template-try-runtime
cp target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/node_template_runtime.wasm runtime-try-runtime.wasm
```

Run the `follow-chain` subcommand:

```
./node-template-try-runtime \
    try-runtime \
    --runtime runtime-try-runtime.wasm \ 
    -lruntime=debug \
    follow-chain \
    --uri ws://localhost:9944
```

Output:

```
2023-03-17 16:22:15.614  INFO main try-runtime::cli: subscribing to "chain_subscribeFinalizedHeads" / "chain_unsubscribeFinalizedHeads"    
2023-03-17 16:22:15.620  INFO main remote-ext: since no prefix is filtered, the data for all pallets will be downloaded    
2023-03-17 16:22:15.623  INFO main remote-ext: scraping key-pairs from remote at block height 0x6eb4ba25d48529972a1f1a5e1ffebbe5172c39029dc96dacef565291f316b165    
2023-03-17 16:22:15.623  INFO main remote-ext: adding data for hashed prefix: 3a6368696c645f73746f726167653a64656661756c743a, took 0s    
2023-03-17 16:22:15.626  INFO main remote-ext: Querying a total of 232 keys from prefix , splitting among 10 threads, 24 keys per thread    
2023-03-17 16:22:15.637  INFO main remote-ext: adding data for hashed prefix: , took 0s    
2023-03-17 16:22:15.637  INFO main remote-ext: adding data for hashed key: 3a636f6465    
2023-03-17 16:22:15.639  INFO main remote-ext: adding data for hashed key: 26aa394eea5630e07c48ae0c9558cef7f9cce9c888469bb1a0dceaa129672ef8    
2023-03-17 16:22:15.639  INFO main remote-ext: adding data for hashed key: 26aa394eea5630e07c48ae0c9558cef702a5c1b19ab7a04f536c519aca4983ac    
2023-03-17 16:22:15.640  INFO main remote-ext: initialized state externalities with storage root 0x77083beb1844ad008a4ceda26c86be09c3f6f06dd05ef35c4d3197dd2f427fc0 and state_version V1    
2023-03-17 16:22:15.649  INFO main try-runtime::cli: original spec: RuntimeString::Owned("node-template")-100, code hash: 7d73847319954ae2408b067399eafaa10d62326205dc12733b605a1772da8b69    
2023-03-17 16:22:15.656  INFO main try-runtime::cli: new spec: RuntimeString::Owned("node-template")-100, code hash: 2318954729d897d8a61012be4e7faa2cc60b9c46480c33591cf21b3ef5abde9b    
2023-03-17 16:22:15.698 ERROR main runtime: panicked at 'Bad input data provided to execute_block: Codec error', /Users/bruno/src/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:351:1    
2023-03-17 16:22:15.705 ERROR main try-runtime::cli: failed to execute block 199 due to Input("failed to execute TryRuntime_execute_block: Execution aborted due to trap: unreachable")    
2023-03-17 16:22:19.812 ERROR main runtime: panicked at 'Bad input data provided to execute_block: Codec error', /Users/bruno/src/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:351:1    
2023-03-17 16:22:19.812 ERROR main try-runtime::cli: failed to execute block 200 due to Input("failed to execute TryRuntime_execute_block: Execution aborted due to trap: unreachable")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug and [an issue has been opened](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/13696).

I'm not sure if this is the SE etiquette is for these scenarios (or what is), but I will keep this answer updated as progress is made on the issue.

Edit: The issue has been identified and a PR opened (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13794)

Comment: This PR has been merged into `master` and I can confirm it is now working!

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical error and it means that the "**block format**" (encoding/decoding) between the chain that's currently *running* (remove or local) and the new runtime that you compiled and passed to the tool are not compatible.

Quoting the documentation of [the command](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/try_runtime_cli/enum.Command.html#variant.FollowChain):

> This can only work if the block format between the remote chain and the new runtime being tested has remained the same, otherwise block decoding might fail.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong or skipped a step. I updated my question with steps to reproduce. If you can help that would be great!